# JSON Schema - using oneOf inside an items array

Tags: json, validation, schema

I would like to use an array (items) in my schema. Each object in the array can be one of "frame-type" as outlined in the schema.

The schema I am developing is given below:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "Campaign_name",
    "Legals"
  ],
  "properties": {
  "Campaign_name": {
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 3
  },
  "Legals": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "legal-button-label": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 6
    },
    "legal-text": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 15
    }
  }
},
"Banner_120x600": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "serve-backup": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "choice": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "yes",
            "no"
          ]
        },
        "image": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^([a-zA-Z|-]+)([.])(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$"
        }
      }
    },
    "background": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^([a-zA-Z|-]+)([.])(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$"
    },
    "logo": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^([a-zA-Z|-]+)([.])(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$"
    },
    "loop": {
      "type": "integer",
      "enum": [
        0,
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    "frames": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "maxItems": 6,
      "items": {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/frame-type/INTRO-FRAME"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/frame-type/OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"frame-type": {
    "INTRO-FRAME": {},
    "OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-1": {}
  }
}
```

However the JSON doesn't validate against the schema. And the JSON I am developing is given below:

```
{
  "Campaign_name": "OSM DT DATA",
  "Legals": {
    "legal-button-label": "Click for Legals",
    "legal-text": "Requires 3G/Wi-Fi. Content depends..."
  },
  "Banner_120x600": {
    "serve-backup": {
  "choice": "no",
  "image": "backup.jpg"
},
"background": "background.png",
"logo": "sky-logo.png",
"loop": 2,
"frames": [
  {
    "type": "INTRO-FRAME"
  },
  {
    "type": "OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-1"
  }
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"oneOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "#/frame-type/INTRO-FRAME"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "#/frame-type/OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-1"
      }
    ]
```

both achemas are empty, and oneOf fails if an object matches more than one schema, which will always be the case because any document matches an empty schema. You may change oneOf to anyOf.

Comment: I populated the Schemas and it still fails to validate.

Comment: how did you populate them and how are you validating it?

Comment: Hi, I found a solution which doesn't use oneOf. I'll update the question and answer it. Thanks for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    "frames": {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "type" : { "enum" : ["INTRO-FRAME"] }   
                }   
            },
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "type" : { "enum" : ["OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-1"] }    
                }   
            },
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "type" : { "enum" : ["OFFER-FRAME-TYPE-2"] }    
                }   
            },
            {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties" : {
                    "type" : { "enum" : ["CONTENT-FRAME"] } 
                }   
            }
        ]
    }
```

I removed the use of "oneOf" and provided an array of objects to validate against.